# How to prevent interceptor call after action if any exception occure during respective action execution

Tags: struts2

I want to prevent interceptor call after action if any exception occurs during action execution in struts2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214532/573032

Comment: can we disable interceptor on certain conditions?

Comment: If you explore who is calling interceptor, then remove the code on that line.